# How to assign C# dynamic variable properties to another dynamic object?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, reflection, types

I'm trying to write a function which creates an object of Type t and assign its properties.

```
    internal static object CreateInstanceWithParam(Type t, dynamic d)
    {
        //dynamic obj =  t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { d }).Invoke(new object[] { d });

        dynamic obj =  t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });
        foreach (var prop in d.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            //prop.Name, 
            //prop.GetValue(d, null);

            // assign the properties and corresponding values to newly created object ???
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Then I should be able to use this for any kind of class types like

```
IUser user = (IUser)CreateInstanceWithParam(userType, new { UserID = 0, Name = "user abc", LoginCode = "abc", DefaultPassword = "xxxxxx" });

IUnit newUnit = (IUnit)CreateInstanceWithParam(unitType, new { ID = 3, Code = "In", Name = "Inch", Points = "72" })
```

How can I assign the property `prop.Name` to `obj`?

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` at all? If you're doing everything with reflection, I can't see that you're actually doing anything that makes use of it being `dynamic`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about `Reflection` namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're just trying to copy properties, you don't need `dynamic` at all:

```
internal static object CreateInstanceWithParam(Type type, object source)
{
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var sourceProperty in d.GetType()
                                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                   BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        var targetProperty = type.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
        // TODO: Check that the property is writable, non-static etc
        if (targetProperty != null)
        {
            object value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
            targetProperty.SetValue(instance, value);
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not copying properties. Now the values are just hard-coded as given in the question. I'm just trying to decouple two assemblies.

Comment: @SenJacob maybe investigate automapper?

Comment: @SenJacob: Well what *are* you trying to do? If you're going to "assign the property `prop.Name` to `obj`" you need to have a value... what value do you want? Your comment says: "assign the properties and corresponding values to newly created object" - in what way is that not copying properties?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for my bad English.. I meant that I'm not copying properties of another object I already have. the properties and values are given as a dynamic object like `new { UserID = 0, Name = "user abc", LoginCode = "abc", DefaultPassword = "xxxxxx" }`

Comment: @SenJacob that is not a "dynamic object"; that is an instance of an *anonymous type*, which is actually a regular static-typed `class`; the only interesting things about it are that a: we don't create the class ourselves (the compiler does), and b: we do not know the type-name

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, it seems I've to learn a lot before proceeding :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using `dynamic` would probably be a *bad* thing here; the objects you are passing in are instances of anonymous types - no need for `dynamic`. In particular, `dynamic` member access is not the same as reflection, and you cannot guarantee that an object described as `dynamic` will return *anything* interesting from `.GetType().GetProperties()`; consider `ExpandoObject`, etc.

However, `FastMember` (available on NuGet) may be useful:

```
internal static object CreateInstanceWithParam(Type type, object template)
{
    TypeAccessor target = TypeAccessor.Create(type),
        source = TypeAccessor.Create(template.GetType());
    if (!target.CreateNewSupported)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot create new instance");
    if (!source.GetMembersSupported)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot enumerate members");
    object obj = target.CreateNew();
    foreach (var member in source.GetMembers())
    {
        target[obj, member.Name] = source[template, member.Name];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

In particular, this can use the `dynamic` API just as easily as the reflection API, and you never *usually* see the difference.